# How would I find $n^n \pmod 5$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have to find the value of the remainders when $n^n$ is divided by $5$ and sum these from $1$ to $100$.
So how would I find the value of $n^n \pmod 5$ for any $n$.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! When you post a question, please try to include some information about what you've tried so far. Among other things, this makes it more likely that you'll get a helpful answer. For more guidelines about asking questions, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: You only need to compute $n^n$ for $n < 20$. Essentially take any $n$ and let your new $n$ be $n (mod 20)$. I believe this has to do with the fact the $5*20 = 100$ but I forget ....

Comment: notice you have to only know the units digit to see the remainder modulus $5$

Answer (score 3):

When $n\equiv m \ (\operatorname{mod} 20)$, we have $n^n \equiv m^m \ (\operatorname{mod} 5)$, because we can compute the bases modulo $5$ and the exponents modulo $4$.  So our sum includes the same $20$ residues $5$ times each.  So the full sum must be $0\ (\operatorname{mod} 5)$.

Comment: When the base is $0$ mod $5$, there is no contribution to the sum. When the base is something else, say $b$, then $b^0$, $b^1$, $b^2$,  and $b^3$ will all appear among the reduced terms. And these will all be distinct...